# How add value in second row into first row?

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to add a new columns from a values of 'Pr' in second rows for each value same id and date.

Input a:

| ID | Date order | Date restock | Pr | Infos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 778005 | 2022-04-07 11:34:46.0 | NaN | 87.0;113001.0;00 | a |
| 778005 | 2022-04-07 11:34:46.0 | NaN | 87.0;113159.0;FC | at |
| 7001 | 2021-12-10 13:50:46.0 | 2021-12-13 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;271007.0;BV | b |
| 7001 | 2021-12-10 13:50:46.0 | 2021-12-13 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;286005.0;BV | bt |
| 778005 | 2022-05-24 12:22:56.0 | NaN | 87.0;113001.0;00 | cc |
| 778005 | 2022-05-24 12:22:56.0 | NaN | 87.0;113159.0;FC | cct |
| 778005 | 2022-05-23 10:49:34.0 | 2022-05-29 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;113001.0;00 | d |
| 778005 | 2022-05-23 10:49:34.0 | 2022-05-29 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;113159.0;FC | dt |
| 7001 | 2022-01-06 08:48:01.0 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;271007.0;BV | rr |
| 7001 | 2022-01-06 08:48:01.0 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;286005.0;BV | rrt |

Output:

| ID | Date order | Date restock | Pr_1 | Infos | Pr_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 778005 | 2022-04-07 11:34:46.0 | NaN | 87.0;113001.0;00 | a | 87.0;113159.0;FC |
| 7001 | 2021-12-10 13:50:46.0 | 2021-12-13 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;271007.0;BV | b | 87.0;286005.0;BV |
| 778005 | 2022-05-24 12:22:56.0 | NaN | 87.0;113001.0;00 | cc | 87.0;113159.0;FC |
| 778005 | 2022-05-23 10:49:34.0 | 2022-05-29 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;113001.0;00 | d | 87.0;113159.0;FC |
| 7001 | 2022-01-06 08:48:01.0 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00.0 | 87.0;271007.0;BV | rr | 87.0;286005.0;BV |

I wrote this code but **ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape**

```
out = (a.pivot('ID', 'Date restock', 'Pr')
       .add_prefix('Pr_').fillna(0)
       .assign(type= a.groupby([['ID', 'Date order', 'Date restock']])['Pr'].first())
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(columns=[None]))
out
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try including `'Infos'` in the columns to `groupby`? After all, those values also match for each pair, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

taking cumcount to identify the duplicate rows, then concatenating the duplicate row as a column with the original df, backfilling the null values and then keeping only the first row

```
df['cc'] = df.groupby(['Date order']).cumcount()
df2=pd.concat([df, 
           df[df['cc'] == 1][[ 'Pr']]],  axis=1).fillna(method='bfill')
df2 = df2[df['cc'] == 0].drop(columns='cc')
df2
```

```
    ID      Date order                       Date restock   Pr               Infos  Pr
0   778005  2022-04-07 11:34:46.0   NaN                     87.0;113001.0;00    a   87.0;113159.0;FC
2   7001    2021-12-10 13:50:46.0   2021-12-13 00:00:00.0   87.0;271007.0;BV    b   87.0;286005.0;BV
4   778005  2022-05-24 12:22:56.0   NaN                     87.0;113001.0;00    cc  87.0;113159.0;FC
6   778005  2022-05-23 10:49:34.0   2022-05-29 00:00:00.0   87.0;113001.0;00    d   87.0;113159.0;FC
8   7001    2022-01-06 08:48:01.0   2022-01-13 00:00:00.0   87.0;271007.0;BV    rr  87.0;286005.0;BV
```